# What's the point of :promptfind after all

Tags: gvim, search, macvim

Not sure if it's an appropriate question. But I just can't help wondering, why would any Vim user find it necessary to invoke a GUI search prompt instead of search using `/` or `?`, why would the designer of `gvim`, `MacVim` etc. want to add this feature. Or is it because they're just quite some inherent feature of a GUI app anyways?

Comment: Hopefully people don't deem it off-topic, because a similar one was asked there http://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2455/what-additional-features-do-gvim-and-or-macvim-offer-compared-to-vim-inside-a-te

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`:promptfind` and related commands are useful for the *easy mode* (`evim`), which according to `:help easy` sets Vim up to *work like most click-and-type editors*. As Notepad has such a find dialog, and users coming from such editors expect it / initially feel better with it, Vim has it, too. I personally wouldn't recommend this way for switching to Vim, though.