# Escape sequences from external commands cluttering output in GVim

Tags: external-command, gvim

One of the reasons i prefer to run Vim from a terminal instead of running gVim is that the output of external gets cluttered up by escape sequences each time I execute commands like `ls` and `grep` that I have aliased to colorize the output in my `.bashrc`.

When executing `:!ls` I get output that looks like this:

```
[0m[01;34mDesktop[0m    [01;34mDocuments[0m    [01;34mDownloads[0m
[01;34mGit[0m    [01;34mMail[0m    [01;34mMusic[0m
[01;34mPictures[0m    [01;34mProgramming[0m
[01;34mPublic[0m    [01;34mSoftware[0m    [01;34mTemplates[0m    todo.txt    [01;34mVideos0m
```

Screenshot here:[image]

Try executing `:!vi` in gVim and your entire screen will explode.

Is there a solution to this problem? Is it possible to make gVim discard escape sequences when printing the output of an external command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the manual of those commands: they may allow you to define when to show colors or not.

`ls`, for example, has the `--color=auto` option that makes it show colors only when possible.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that gVim doesn't emulate a full terminal, in this particular case, it doesn't recognize colour codes.

This is simply something you can't do in gVim, unless you spawn a new terminal with `:!xterm -e 'ls && read'`, use `:!/bin/ls` to prevent loading your `ls` alias which adds colours, or filter the colors with something like `:!ls | sed 's|\x1b\[[;0-9]*m||g'` (I have that `sed` command as a shell alias).

See also: [What additional features do gVim and/or MacVim offer compared to Vim inside a terminal emulator?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/2458/51).