# How should I move the cursor when running shell by using :sh?

Tags: macvim, bash

[image]

If I use arrow keys, I will get the text in the above picture.

Comment: Very similar (possibly duplicate): [Escape sequences from external commands cluttering output in GVim](http://vi.stackexchange.com/q/4152/51).

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you're using Macvim/GVim. GVim isn't a full terminal emulator, so don't expect everything to work. You can't use arrows, but you can <kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Comment: Is there an elegent way except applying plugins like ConqueTerm to run interactive command in GVim?

Comment: @MrDwZ not really. When in GVim, I just do `:!`